# Mvc _layout Request.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know I am asking a valid question or not. I am developing MVC web application. In this I have `Home/Index` method. When I run the website it show me http://localhost:25537/ in `url`  which is pointing to `Home/Index` method. On `Index` page I am showing some banner, and some other content. When I login to my site at that time I want to route to same page i.e. `http://localhost:25537/` which is points to `Home/Index` but the content should be changed.

This is my `routeconfig`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How can I implement such `view`? How can I route to same page but content should changed?

If I used `Request.IsAuthenticate` in `Index` page then it shows after login. But I have one doubt. This `Home/index` is defined as `[AllowAnonymous]` but after login it should be `[Authorize]`.

Answer (score 2):

> If I used `Request.IsAuthenticate` in Index page then it shows after login.

That's exactly how you do it.  In your view you would wrap the authenticated-only content in a check for that.  Something like:

```
<div>
    public content
</div>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div>
        authenticated-only content
    </div>
}
```

That content would then be delivered to the client if and only if the user making the request is authenticated.

> This Home/index is defined as `[AllowAnonymous]` but after login it should be `[Authorize]`.

No it shouldn't.  The index action still allows anonymous access.  The view it returns simply has some sections which don't display for anonymous users.  But the action itself can still be requested by those users.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So My implementation is valid right? it doesn't matter after login the method `[Authorize]` or `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: Actually I am not getting what should be the title of this question. That's why I put `Mvc _layout Request.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: @AjayPunekar: It matters in the sense that those attributes will determine if the request requires authorization or if it can be made by anonymous users.  In the vast majority of cases, `Home/Index` allows anonymous access.  If you want users to be able to visit `Home/Index` before they login, it needs to allow anonymous access.

Comment: @AjayPunekar: It's not clear what you mean.  What are you redirecting from and what are you redirecting to?  Why are you performing this redirect?

Comment: When I run the site it shows me default controller and it's action i.e. Index page. I am showing banner, some other content on Index page. When I login So I don't want to show in url something like this `http://localhost:25537/home/someView`. I only want to show `http://localhost:25537/`

Comment: @AjayPunekar: If you want to redirect the user upon login, then return a redirect response on the login action.  Something like `return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");`  That would send the user to the `Home/Index` action after login.  It doesn't matter if the address bar in the web browser explicitly *says* `Home/Index` or not, it's still going to the same action.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if your controller action is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The attribute only checks if you are allowed to view the page without login.

So in your view you can simply use:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
    // some Stuff you want to show if the user has logged in
}
```